# Bash: edit a file at a specific line and column regardless of keyword to replace

Tags: bash, sed

I am trying to edit a numeric value in a file with `sed` command. I know the exact line and column of the value needs to change.

Let's say;

Line: 2, Column: 21

and this is the file I am trying to edit, i.e. `example.txt`

```
hello
this is my number = 131;
world
```

However, this numeric value may vary in terms of digits, e,g, 30 or 130.

If I want to set this number to 32,

how can I find and replace this numeric value? Assuming that I do not know the numeric value beforehand.

So far, I can only use `sed` with known keywords and lines;

`sed -i '' -e '2s/131/32/' example.txt`

Comment: Please do add your efforts in form of code in your question, which is highly encouraged on SO(not my downvote btw).

Comment: Thanks for adding your efforts. Could you please do add samples of input and expected output in your question in more clear way to make your question more clear, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E '2s/(= ).*/\132/' input_file
hello
this is my number = 32
world
```

Comment: @HarunSasmaz sed -E "2s/(= ).*/\1$VALUE/" input_file

Answer (score 1):

To replace anything at a particular offset, capture that many characters and replace everything after them.

```
sed -i '' -e '2s/^\(....................\).*/\132/' example.txt
```

Of course, if you can predict what those character are, try to be more specific:

```
sed -i '' -e '2s/^this is my number = .*/this is my number = 32/' example.txt
```

To replace any digits at the end of the indicated line, try

```
sed -i '' -e '2s/[0-9][0-9]* *$/32/' example.txt
```

(Your `sed` might have an `-E` or `-r` option which allows you to say `.{20}` instead of `....................`.)

Answer (score 0):

In the assumption that there is always a white space that separates the last column/field, which is what your sample/data looks like, Something like:

```
sed '2s/[0-9]\{1,\}.$/32/' file.txt
```

---

- `[0-9]` is a [Bracket Expression](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05) pattern/regex that means any digit/number.
- `{1,}` is a quantifier that means one or more, the `\` is just for escaping the `{` and `}`, since `sed` defaults to [BRE](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03).
- A dot [.](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_04) means any character/string that should match the trailing `;` in your pattern, change it to a `;` to match a a literal `;`.
- `$` is an [anchor](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_08) which means at the end.

Comment: this does not work, I guess because I forgot to add ; at the end. Can you check the new example file?

Comment: Updated the answer to match your pattern.